# Undeclared identifier error when importing from implementation

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to import values from an NSArray that I created in my implementation file, but it doesn't seem to be importing properly, because I'm receiving a `Use of undeclared identifier` error in Xcode.

I'm assuming this is because a property in the implementation is private, and so other classes can't access it. I created topCategory1 and topCategory2 in my implementation file however, so I'm not sure how to make it publicly accessible. Any ideas?

SearchCategoryChooserViewController.m:

```
#import "SearchCategoryChooserViewController.h"
#import "SearchViewController.m"

@interface SearchCategoryChooserViewController ()

@end

@implementation SearchCategoryChooserViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];




    UIButton *category1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    category1.frame = CGRectMake(10, 120, 300, 35);
    [category1 setTitle: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", topCategory1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [category1 addTarget:self action:@selector(myButtonClick:)    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview: category1];


    UIButton *category2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    category2.frame = CGRectMake(10, 180, 300, 35);
    [category2 setTitle: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", topCategory2] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [category2 addTarget:self action:@selector(myButtonClick:)    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview: category2];


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

SearchViewController.m (Class I want to import from):

```
#import "SearchViewController.h"

@interface SearchViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *itemSearch;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *nextButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *topCategory1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *topCategory2;

@end

@implementation SearchViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.nextButtonOutlet addTarget:self action:@selector(nextButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}




- (IBAction)nextButton:(id)sender
{
    if (self.itemSearch.text.length > 0) {
        [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"eBayCategorySearch"
                           withParameters:@{@"item": self.itemSearch.text}
                                    block:^(NSDictionary *result, NSError *error) {
                                        NSLog(@"'%@'", result);


                                            NSArray *resultArray = [result objectForKey:@"results"];


                                                NSDictionary *dictionary0 = [resultArray objectAtIndex:0];
                                                NSNumber *numberOfTopCategories = [dictionary0 objectForKey:@"Number of top categories"];

                                                NSDictionary *dictionary1 = [resultArray objectAtIndex:1];
                                                NSNumber *topCategories = [dictionary1 objectForKey:@"Top categories"];

                                                NSDictionary *dictionary2 = [resultArray objectAtIndex:2];
                                                NSNumber *numberOfMatches = [dictionary2 objectForKey:@"Number of matches"];

                                                NSDictionary *dictionary3 = [resultArray objectAtIndex:3];
                                                NSNumber *userCategoriesThatMatchSearch = [dictionary3 objectForKey:@"User categories that match search"];

                                            NSArray *topCategoriesArray = [dictionary1 objectForKey:@"Top categories"];
                                                NSString *topCategory1 = [topCategoriesArray objectAtIndex:0];
                                                NSString *topCategory2 = [topCategoriesArray objectAtIndex:1];


                                        if (!error) {



                                            if ([numberOfMatches intValue] == 1 ){
                                                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowMatchCenterSegue" sender:self];
                                            }


                                            else if ([numberOfMatches intValue] == 2){
                                                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowUserCategoryChooserSegue" sender:self];

                                            }


                                            else if ([numberOfMatches intValue] == 0 && [numberOfTopCategories intValue] == 1) {
                                                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowCriteriaSegue" sender:self];
                                            }

                                            else if ([numberOfMatches intValue] == 0 && [numberOfTopCategories intValue] == 2) {
                                                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowSearchCategoryChooserSegue" sender:self];
                                            }

                                        }
                                    }];
    }
}






#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
//    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ShowSearchCategoryChooserSegue"]){
//        SearchCategoryChooserViewController *controller = (SearchCategoryChooserViewController *) segue.destinationViewController;
//        controller.itemSearch.text = self.itemSearch.text;
//        }


}






@end
```

Comment: You should use `self.topCategory1` and move their declaration to the header file inside the `@interface`. I'm assuming `SearchCategoryChooserViewController` is a sublclass of `SearchViewController`?

Comment: No it's not a subclass, but now that you mention it, subclassing it might be a good idea. If I subclass it and put their declaration in the header file, will it be able to pull the information from the implementation file? Sorry I'm still a bit new to this.

Comment: @user3561379 Yes you will be. All public properties/ivars/functions are inherited by subclasses.

Comment: They are **all** inherited regardless of being specified in the header or not. Its just their access/visibility is only allowed if they are specified in the header, or redeclared in a class extension. You could not have a "public" method, and redefine it in a subclass and that implementation would be used instead of the superclasses one.

Comment: @lead_the_zeppelin I laid out the references and I'm getting an error stating 'Cannot find interface declaration for SearchViewController'. Here's how I did it: http://codeshare.io/RwWcl

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: there is a circular reference going on in your code. By a rule of thumb, base class **SHOULD NOT** import sub class header files.

Comment: Never import a .m file.